# local setup of bugzilla in my machine

Tags: perl, apache2, bugzilla

Need to configure bugzilla locally to my machine. I am having the bugzilla code base, apache 2.2, active perl 5.0, my SQL

I have installed appache HTTP server in my system. when i tried giving localhost in IE it displayed like it works.

But i don't know where to add the bugzilla codes to display in the localhost. how and where to deploy the codes in appache.